# How to get coordinates of a draggable marker Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

When my map is ready, it has several `draggable` markers on it. I would like to know new coordinates of a marker when it was moved. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:
First thing you have to do is to set `OnMarkerDragListener` on the `mMap` object:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

                }
            });
```

Now it is possible to get position of a marker:
`someMarker.getPosition().latitude`, `someMarker.getPosition().longitude`

Don't forget to make a marker `draggable`:

```
someMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(defPoint1).title("someMraker").draggable(true));
```